# EF code-first foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I have a class Question

CompareItems store CurrentQuestion-to-OtherQuestion compare information.

```
public class Question 
{
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionMark> CompareItems { get; set; }
}


public class QuestionMark
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Question { get; set; } //Store ID of OtherQuestion
    public decimal Mark { get; set; }
}
```

When I delete some question A I need that all QuestionMark where QuestionMark.Question == A.Id also deleted, because it's no need to have compare information if question not exist. How it possible to do that without making QuestionMark.Question an entity? Maybe EF have some rule in Fluent-API to set that QuestionMark.Question is foreign key on Question entity?

*I don't wont to make QuestionMark.Question as entity because it will need to change current solution lot - is a first. Also, question is a quite heavy entity, and to load it multiple time to assign value or delete or something else will be press on performance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible to change app to use Entities instead of id, because EF use lazy loading by default and it will not caused performance problems. And I think that using just id instead of entity possible with some fluent API settings or attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to make a navigational property `Question` in `QuestionMark` class then you need to manually create a foreign key with "cascade delete". Then when every a question is deleted the **database will delete** the related `QuestionMark` records.

However this approach has a problem with EF. Because EF does not know there is a "cascade delete" relationship among these entities. So there can be inconsistencies within the locally tracked entities in EF.

You have not given a reason as to why you do not want to map the relationship in EF but I highly advice you against it.

Comment: To add, if the reason is "because I want to access the Question number from a QuestionMark object", you can expose both the foreign key property and the navigation property.